# Cannot RDP to Windows 7 with Remmina on 12.04

Tags: rdp, remmina

Since I upgraded to 12.04, I am unable to RDP to a Windows 7 server. All I can see is a pop-up that says "Uable to connect to RDP server ". I am able to RDP using Vinagre, so that rules out any issues with my router or the Windows server.
As far as I can tell, there are no logs from Remmina and the Debug window shows a blank.
Any one got any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 156):

I too had the problem that I could connect to a Windows 7 machine and suddenly (after weeks) I got this error:
Unable to connect to RDP server

In my case I deleted the entry from ~/.freerdp/known_hosts and it then worked fine.

Comment: Same goes for current debian testing, version 0.9.99.1.

Comment: I had multiple entries for the same machine (because of various assigned IP's over time by DHCP. Removed them all, and voila, worked (again). Thanks!

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well. Apparently the server fingerprint changed and I needed to resync. A more verbose error would have been nice on remmina's part.

Comment: amaziing !!! I worked also for me. (Ubuntu 14.04 TLS) Thank you very much (+1)

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: This worked for me as well, but it's a bit concerning why it should. When I diff the new file with the old `diff .freerdp/known_hosts{,.bak}` I see that the host key has changed. I encountered this issue after disconnecting the remote session (leaving the account logged in on the remote), going to bed, and then waking up the next morning to find that I couldn't re-connect.  After reboots on the local and remote machine, restarting the term service (Windows Server 2008), I found the solution here. Any idea why the host key should have changed?

Comment: I also have an ssh server (cygwin) on the remote and I was able to connect via ssh without issue so that host key apparently did not change, strangely enough.

Comment: Linux Mint 18: the file is now located here: ~/.config/freerdp/known_hosts

Comment: XUbuntu 16.04LTS its located in `~/.config/freerdp/known_hosts2`. You can search for the file with `$ locate "freerdp/known"`.

Answer (score 71):

Click Advanced tab in your Remote Desktop Preferences and choose RDP in Security drop down menu and save.

So far it works for me.

Comment: Or more generally, choose the authentication type that the server supports, NLA in my case.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me, too.

Comment: Yup, I needed this to get mine to work as well

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem, getting the "Unable to connect to RDP server" message using Remmina and Ubuntu 12.04 to a Windows 7 machine.

It worked fine for weeks and then suddenly stopped.

What fixed it was going to ~/.freerdp/certs and deleting the problem server from that file.

The next time it connected, it asked for a new cert and worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem. Like you I had no output when running remmina on the command line and the debug window was blank. I solved this by removing the line in the file `~/.freerdp` corresponding to the problem server.

Comment: filename is: ~/.freerdp/known_hosts

Answer (score 8):

I have no idea why it worked, but I started changing settings one at a time. When I edited the connection properties, I looked on the "advanced" tab and changed the security from "negotiate" to "TLS", and voila, everything works.

Strangely, "negotiate" still works on the laptop, but at least I'm back in business with my bigger monitor :)

Answer (score 5):

I haven't had any files in ~/.freerdp/certs/ so I went ahead and cleared the file ~/.freerdp/known_hosts with this command:

```
echo "" > ~/.freerdp/known_hosts
```

Be careful! This will erase the entire file. I only had one entry, so it was okay.

Afterwards connecting to the server Remmina asked me to accept the servers certificate, which I did, and everything was finally back to normal. I suspect that an update of Remmina or the RDP protocoll might be the issue.

Comment: I can't imagine why Remmina can't come up with a better error message than "Unable To Connect" but your solution saved many hairs on my head!!

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this issue by activating the console mode for windows 2003.

Advanced ->
Protocol RDP
security = RDP
tick: Attach to console

Comment: This works fine for me, I was trying to connect to a Windows Server 2012 R2, so the last option was that I was missing. Thanks!