# MPLS or VPN in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: networking, vpn

This question has two parts-

1 - At work I have a MPLS network setup, where we configure the internet explorer to connect to a gateway server (I have the url and port) to enable us to use the MPLS connection to link to our work websites.

Is there a way to get that setup to work in ubuntu so that I can connect to the same MPLS network from my home?

2 - Alternatively, we also use the Juniper Networks VPN utility to connect to the VPN by going to a website and getting some client side software installed. (NetConnect)

I have searched on google and all I could find was the acceptance that getting that Juniper network software to be configured correctly and working is difficult.

But that was some time ago. Has someone tackled that problem? Or can someone help me get it cracked?

Alternate softwares/methods that get me connected to the work network are also welcomed.

Comment: I checked out a few open source VPN clients, and they seem to need some settings to set up. Is there any method anyone knows to run in windows to check those settings?

Comment: The Juniper utility, is it not able to provide a PPTP VPN service so you could just configure a username & password then use the built in VPN connection in Ubuntu to connect to your work? For example at our office we use Cisco VPN routers which we configure the relevant user/pass under the PPTP Server section, then do a quick and easy setup of the VPN connection on Ubuntu, click the connection and we have secure access to our work LAN.

Comment: @charlie Did the answer below work for you? If it worked consider accepting the answer as the correct one, even though it does not answer your MPLS part of the question.

Comment: @user68186..>Thanks.. I am aware of how the forum works, but I had bad net connectivity these past few weeks... I'll try the below answers and then will accept the one that works, or comes closest

Answer (score 1):

**Juniper should work out of the box for 32 bit Ubuntu 13.04 and OpenJDK 7.**

You will need to install the OpenJDK JRE and the icedtea plugin. For 64bit version you need both 64bit Java (to be used as default) as well as 32 bit Java. See [Juniper setup on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136194/juniper-setup-on-12-04/152724#152724) for details.

When you start Juniper for the first time you will get a couple of pop-ups. Click **Always Trust** button for the first and in the terminal type pop-up enter the sudo password as requested.

Then the Network Connect Window will popup. If the Network Connect Window opens and closes, you probably have `icedtea-6-plugin` installed together with (or instead of) `icedtea-7-plugin`. Remove the icedtea-6-plugin.

Wait till the connection is complete and all the fields including the IP address are populated. Now you are ready to connect to your office computer.

**For RDP**

Open `remmina` from the Dash and enter the remote computer's ID, user ID, password, and domain name. You may want to use the same settings as the RDP client in Windows.

If you get the error "Uable to connect to RDP server", delete the entry from `~/.freerdp/known_hosts`. See [Cannot RDP to Windows 7 with Remmina on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157723/cannot-rdp-to-windows-7-with-remmina-on-12-04).

**For Citrix**

If your office's Juniper web page includes a link to connecting to a virtual server using the Citrix Java version, then you should be able to able to click on the link and connect once the Juniper Connect makes the connection.

Hope this helps