# Can I transfer files alo copy paste in Remmina (or another RDP client) on 13.04 while connected to a Windows 7?

Tags: 13.04, windows-7, rdp, remmina

When I connect to a remote Windows 7 using as FROM a Windows 7 machine, I can copy paste files between machines. How can I enable that feature while using as FROM Ubuntu?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it with FreeRDP (freerdp-x11 package) via terminal:

```
xfreerdp +drives /u:username /v:server_address:server_port
```

**+drives** tells FreeRDP to connect all your local drives.

If you dont have it you can install it:

```
sudo apt-get install freerdp-x11
```

Comment: would you mind if I ask what can be the reason of this problem on connection? I type `xfreerdp -u dk -p '1234!56' +drives example.com` but it gives me the error `transport_connect: getaddrinfo (Name or service not known)
Error: protocol security negotiation failure`

Comment: Your error can have many reasons. You can try to explicitly set protocol security other than negotiate (which is default) with switch `/sec:<rdp|tls|nla|ext> force specific protocol security`. You can also look at this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/157723/cannot-rdp-to-windows-7-with-remmina-on-12-04, even if it seems it is not directly related to your problem

Comment: And you should open separate question, comments are not designed for asking another questions! You will also get more attention with separate question.

Comment: actually I thought that this comment is related to this answer, so I posted it here. In my case everything is fine after removing `+drives`. Could you tell me where did you get this option? Cause I do not see it in the `--help` prompt

Comment: sorry, you didn't mentioned that without `+drives` it works. You should find official documentation here: https://github.com/awakecoding/FreeRDP-Manuals/blob/master/User/FreeRDP-User-Manual.markdown

Answer (score 4):

Thank you @betatester07 for this `+drives` hint! My hints below:

- You can also use `/drive:name,mountpoint` directive to provide only a given path to a remote client :-)
- You can put all parameters into a text file (i.e. `~/client.rdp` with each parameter into single line) to have your favorite configuration stored and quickly accessed:

```
/drive:stuff,/mnt/stuff
/u:USER_NAME_HERE
/v:CLIENT_IP_HERE
/size:1080x1920
/f
```

Now you can now simply connect each time with:

```
xfreerdp ~/client.rdp
```

Tested on FreeBSD :-)

Comment: Hm, with the parameter `/drive:share,/mnt/share`, I have the error `[00:04:49:345] [8881:8881] [ERROR][com.winpr.commandline] - Failed at index 2 [/drive:share,/mnt/share]: PostFilter rule could not be applied`

Answer (score 0):

As a plus side, I wrote a script for the business I work for. That has a Virtual Desktop Infrastructure based on windows. I wrote it to use on Debian based  thin-clients(can probably be adapted for other distros with minor changes). It adds a small GUI wizard for your connection.

Supports most common options :
Options:

- -u                     => Set Username
- -p                     => Set Password
- -d                     => Set Domain
- -h                     => Set Host
- -k                     => Enable Persist Mode which relaunches the prompt whenever you close your connection
- -l                     => Enable Drives Redirection
- -v                     => Enable Debug Mode
  Input commands sent are stored in log/rdp/
- -i                     => Install Script as Binary
- -r                     => Remove Installation
- -m                     => Enable Multi-Monitor
- -a                     => Set Alternate Port

https://github.com/LouisOuellet/rdp