# How do I use dual monitors with Remmina Remote Desktop Client?

Tags: multiple-monitors, rdp, remmina

I am trying to use my two monitors when I use Remmina remote desktop client. There is no option for using all monitors like RDP in Windows.

Does any one know how can I accomplish that with Remmina?

This is the option I'm talking about in Windows RDP:

[image]

Comment: I've added multi monitor support from Remmina 1.4.11, it's still experimental, and I count on some testing to reach a good maturity level.

Comment: Just wanna to give a quick update, thanks to some awesome guys, **multi monitor support is now available for remmina > v1.4.10** ([reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Remmina/comments/lc0bf8/remmina_multi_monitor_support_for_rdp/)). You might need to install a newer version ([here](https://remmina.org/how-to-install-remmina/)). View [here](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/merge_requests/2184) how to enable multi monitor support.

Answer (score 33):

I think that remmina can't do this at the moment.

But you can use the xfreerdp command from your terminal:

```
xfreerdp /multimon /u:username /v:server_address:server_port
```

where `username` is your username on server, `server_address` is server location (IP address or hostname) and `server_port` is port (leave empty without ":" for default port).

If you don't have xfreerdp installed, you can install it from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install freerdp2-x11
```

Comment: I tried to follow your instruction to Win Server 2008 box. Unfortunately getting `Error: protocol security negotiation failure` error. What can be causing it?

Comment: I think you may have similar problem as [user44439](http://askubuntu.com/users/44439/user44439) in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/a/346694/67920) (see first comment under accepted answer)

Comment: As in my answer to that question, the default installed `xfreerdp` for Trusty is 1.0.1 which has no Multimon support - you need the newer version. In addition, be sure that your target RDP server supports it - Windows 7 "Professional" does not (presumably to encourage you to upgrade).

Comment: /d:domain may be useful too

Comment: is this still the case in 2018 ?

Comment: @user230910: as there's not an option to use multiple displays in Remmina  1.2.0-rcgit-29 (git rcgit-29) which is in Ubuntu official repos, I guess that yes, it's still the case

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a workaround for RDPing into Windows. Create a `.rdp` file in windows, open it with a text editor, make sure `multimonitor` is set to 1.  Copy it to your Linux system, open with Remmina in windowed mode (not full screen), and connect.  In the left pane, click the `TOGGLE DYNAMIC RESOLUTION UPDATE`, leaving in window stretch to all your display, and voila!

Answer (score 2):

this works in remmina 1.4.25 it is now a simply checkbox
[image: multimontor checked]

Comment: I'm on Remmina 1.4.26 on manjaro linux and that box isn't there. How peculiar.

Comment: that's quite peculiar indeed

Comment: I have the box but it still not using both monitors :/

Comment: @Emmanouil Chountasisi i don't know what to say, it worked for me

Comment: @EmmanouilChountasis, what worked for me was switching from Wayland to xorg as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370996/remmina-rdp-dual-monitor-support-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-21-10)

Comment: It work me on wayland if memory serves