# Remmina: RDP dual monitor support not working after upgrading to ubuntu 21.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, remmina, 21.10

Before going on, here's the version information about remmina:

```
/snap/remmina/5073/usr/bin/remmina: /snap/remmina/5073/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7: no version information available (required by /snap/remmina/5073/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0)
Load modules from /snap/remmina/current/usr/lib/remmina/plugins
Remmina plugin glibsecret (type=Secret) has been registered, but is not yet initialized/activated. The initialization order is 2000.
The glibsecret secret plugin has been initialized and it will be your default secret plugin

org.remmina.Remmina - SNAP Build - 1.4.21 (git e73ddab1f)

NAME                TYPE            DESCRIPTION                                                     PLUGIN AND LIBRARY VERSION
EXEC                Protocol        Execute a command                                               1.0       
GVNC                Protocol        Remmina VNC plugin for GNOME and KVM                            0.1b      
RDP                 Protocol        RDP - Remote Desktop Protocol                                   RDP plugin: 1.4.21 (Git e73ddab1f), Compiled with libfreerdp 2.4.1 (2.4.1), Running with libfreerdp 2.4.1 (rev 2.4.1), H.264 Yes
RDPF                File            RDP - RDP File Handler                                          RDP plugin: 1.4.21 (Git e73ddab1f), Compiled with libfreerdp 2.4.1 (2.4.1), Running with libfreerdp 2.4.1 (rev 2.4.1), H.264 Yes
RDPS                Preference      RDP - Preferences                                               RDP plugin: 1.4.21 (Git e73ddab1f), Compiled with libfreerdp 2.4.1 (2.4.1), Running with libfreerdp 2.4.1 (rev 2.4.1), H.264 Yes
SPICE               Protocol        SPICE - Simple Protocol for Independent Computing Environments  1.4.21    
VNC                 Protocol        Remmina VNC Plugin                                              1.4.21    
VNCI                Protocol        Remmina VNC listener Plugin                                     1.4.21    
WWW                 Protocol        Remmina web-browser plugin                                      0.1.0     
glibsecret          Secret          Secured password storage in the GNOME keyring                   1.4.21    

Build configuration: HAVE_ARPA_INET_H=1 HAVE_ERRNO_H=1 HAVE_FCNTL_H=1 HAVE_NETDB_H=1 HAVE_NETINET_IN_H=1 HAVE_NETINET_TCP_H=1 HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H=1 HAVE_SYS_UN_H=1 HAVE_TERMIOS_H=1 HAVE_UNISTD_H=1 WITH_AVAHI=ON WITH_CLEANUP=OFF WITH_FREERDP3=OFF WITH_GCRYPT=ON WITH_GVNC=ON WITH_ICON_CACHE=ON WITH_IPP=OFF WITH_LIBRARY_VERSIONING=ON WITH_MANPAGES=ON WITH_NEWS=ON WITH_SSE2=ON WITH_TRANSLATIONS=ON WITH_UPDATE_DESKTOP_DB=ON
Build type:          Release
CFLAGS:              -isystem/builds/Remmina/Remmina/parts/remmina/install/usr/include -isystem/builds/Remmina/Remmina/stage/usr/include -fPIC -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wredundant-decls
Compiler:            GNU, 9.3.0
Target architecture: x64
```

After upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10, it seems like multimonitor support is no longer working properly. I can see the options and they're activated, but the RDP session will only use one of the monitors.

Any clues on what I can do to troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Remmina doesn't fully support Wayland yet.
Since 21.04 Ubuntu uses Wayland as the default display server protocol.
You can switch to Xorg mode when logging on to the desktop and Remmina will work as good as before.

You can change the display server on the Ubuntu login screen. If your desktop is configured to auto login you have to log out and then log in again.

[image: Screenshot of the login screen]

Comment: Hello. I'm not sure if I follow ywhat you're saying. I'm trying to rdp to windows 11 from an ubuntu box...

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks. That was it :)

Comment: This answer works for *Ubuntu 22.04.1 (Jammy Jellyfish)* too.