# Wayland - Screen sharing - Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: xorg, wayland, 23.10, obs-studio

I can't use screen sharing in any app with **Wayland**, I see a **black screen** instead of my screen.

Help me please, I don`t want to switch **Wayland** to **Xorg**.

- Ubuntu 23.10
- Intel Xeon E5-2420 v2
- 500GB HDD
- NVIDIA GT 630 2GB (nouveau)
- 16GB RAM (DDR3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remmina: RDP dual monitor support not working after upgrading to ubuntu 21.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370996/remmina-rdp-dual-monitor-support-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-21-10) This would also seem to apply in your use case too. I don't think it's been upgraded.

Comment: I think this will answer your question - [ans:Screen sharing with Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398720/1450948)