# How to use single-screen machine to access a dual-screen Ubuntu machine via UDP and see both screens?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, vnc

This is a follow up to [How do I use dual monitors with Remmina Remote Desktop Client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344103/how-do-i-use-dual-monitors-with-remmina-remote-desktop-client)

The developer I guess says it's a feature, but added almost 2 years ago at this point. So I have everything up to date.

When using Remmina on a single screen laptop, when it connects to the dual-screen machine, it only shows the primary screen. I cannot figure out any way to get both shown or toggle between them. I've turned on scale, I've turned on "span screen over multiple monitors" and of course I have turned on "Enable multi monitor". These are all settings under the "Basic" tab under the profile I set up for connecting to the dual-screen machine.

Is using legacy VNC compatibility when configuring screen sharing from the dual-screen machine breaking this? (Settings -> Sharing -> Remote Desktop: On) I had that enabled so an android device (using RVNC Connect) could remotely connect to the dual-screen machine. Is there any way to have best of both worlds? Or if disabling legacy VNC mode is necessary, are there alternative Android apps compatible with Ubuntu's screen sharing protocol?