# what is the usage of ~/.freerdp

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

on the home directory there is a hidden folder named  .freerdp. What is that and what is the usage of that? I see this when I searched for this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157723/cannot-rdp-to-windows-7-with-remmina-on-12-04) and I found freerdp directory on the first answer

Comment: In Linux it is called a directory (rather then a folder). Files that start with a dot (.) are hidden. .freerdp is a configuration directory for your user specific settings for freerdp - http://www.freerdp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Linux world, configuration files and directories are usually found in your home folder (`$HOME`, also known as `~/`) and are named as `.nameoftheprogram`. Many are collected in the `~/.config` directory (such as `~/.config/google-chrome`) and others are in your $HOME itself (like `~/.mozilla`).

The one you are asking about is the configuration directory for [FreeRDP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freerdp/):

> FreeRDP is a free remote desktop protocol client that implements RDP following the documentation provided under the Microsoft Open Specification Promise.

That's where your personal FreeRDP settings will be stored.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above the directory stores configuration information. Specifically it stores in a file called known_hosts, a list of trusted servers (their IP and Authentication Hash Key) to which you had connected to previously. This way each time you attempt to connect to known servers, FreeRDP does not need to perform NLA server authentication. 
Further, if you wish to install FreeRDP as a server, then you need to copy certain directories to the ~/.config/freerdp directory as mentioned in step 14 here:
[Can FreeRDP be used as server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475776/can-freerdp-be-used-as-server)